# Using the PreprocessQuery method in a Local Query

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I've a master/detail relationship like the one shown in the picture below

[image]

I need to filter the data shown in the OrderHeaders table so I've edited the **local query** (by clicking the Edit Query link in the screen) but part of the filter is based on a **Computed Property** so I need to use the **PreprocessQuery** method because the Computed Properties doesn't appear in the query's "Filter" section.

But now I've a problem, in the local query the "Write Code" ComboBox is not available like in a Global Query like is shown in the picture below

[image]

So I don't know how to create the PreprocessQuery method in the local query.

Can someone tell me how to create it?

If it's not available for **local queries** is there another way to filter by a Computed Property?

Comment: I see what you mean. Why not create a subquery of Your "orderHeaders" table. Then modify the preProcess method there. If you add a parameter to the query, you'll be able to use it as a filter in preProcess. Then in the main page Create a property, set it in code to your computed string and map it to the query parameter

Comment: @TsSkTo I understand what you mean but I don't know how to bind that property or new Global Query (as you suggest) as the query for the OrderHeaders table. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: That should do it. Play around with it and see if you can get it to work. If you have any questions, just ask ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok first create you subquery from a table. Such as your `ProductsWithouDescription` and `SortedProducts` by right clicking a table and "Adding Query".
(Country is supposed to be the equivalent of you "Headers" table)

[image]

Name the query, then add a parameter to your query of whatever type you need.

[image]

Now write some code for it: (here country is the table I'm using)

[image]

[image]

Note that your NewParameter is now a "Parameter" to your method. This will filter this query to display only the records where the `CountryName` is equal to the parameter. You can have as many parameters as you need.

Now add that data item to your screen.

[image]

Then add a new property of the type you need as well.(Its under Add data Item as well)

I recommend you uncheck *Is required*.

[image]

Here is the basic query layout for my screen. I used a table **Locations** to as an example as every location has a country in my data model. Locations is supposed to the equivalent of  Customer table. If I expand the *locations*(you customers) table I will notice that I can't add my newly created query directly. Also notice the property Created is now displayed.

[image]

If you expand your new query on the left youll see the parameter at the bottom.

[image]

Click on it, get to its properties (F4) and map the parameter to the newly created property.

[image]

Now your filtering parameter is set by that property we just created.

Now you have to set the property before that query can display anything. Heres how to do it:

Select your **Customer**(Mine is locations) table and at the top left click the down arrow next to write code and select the `SelectionChanged' method:

[image]

Now write some code:

[image]

Here My display string is a computed field of Locations. So every time you select something in the locations grid, it will use that "DisplayString" to filter "MynewFavoriteQuery".

Some things to note:

It you make the parameter for your subquery **Optional** the query will display everything without filtering as long as the property is **NULL**. (Actually Im not sure about this one since im using it a little bit differently, but you can play around with it and see what you get)

[image]

If you set your property to **Required** it will cause validation erros on the screen if the property is set to null.

You may also have to fine tune this as the property is always initialized to null when the screen is created. You can edit the "ScreeCreated" method under general in write code to set some value to that property when your screen is first generated.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Someone at the Microsoft forum answer the same you did but my reply is a little longer so I can't paste it here in the comment. Would you read it here  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c8aba095-8282-4e70-b292-bb59f1eda874/using-the-preprocessquery-method-in-a-local-query

Comment: @vcRobe Lightswitch has that neat feature to quickly add related tables to the screen. The problem is that you're stepping out of that. The subquery you created is not gonna show up as a convenient link. But there is a fairly simple coded alternative. All lightswitch is doing is filtering the seconf query by the first. You can do the exact same thing with properties like I mentioned above. I can put some more detailed info if you need it. Let me know

Comment: Yes please, I need more detailed info to do what you're suggesting me because I'm a little lost about it.

Comment: I did step by step what you said and when I run the app I get nothing in the grid that belong to the new query. When I move the mouse over the grid I get the following tooltip "Unable to load data. Please check your network connection and try loading again". Why I get that error? PD: After seen the error I've removed all parameters from the query so the query returns all the rows and I get the same error.

Comment: I did the same steps by steps in a new app in a different PC and it works. So I'll post a new question to understand why can this be happening. Now it works but when I add a new row in the grid the column of the relationship with the master table is not filled automatically. I think this is the last step to finish it. How can I add the column's value of the selected row of the master table in the detail table?

Comment: Did you get the red `x` ? That's a generic error and it tells you very little. Try debugging step by step. The first thing would be to create a brand new sub-query without any parameters and without the pre-process method and add it to your screen. If that still gives you an error(it shouldn't) then it's something to do with your data source. Then add everything step by step while testing to see what each addendum does to the display grid. That should help you narrow down the problem

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you need, but you can access the selected value of any query by the query.selectedItem.field like in setting the property. If you want to add a new record to the details it uses something like query.addNew(). Also if this answered you question please mark as answer

Comment: Of course I'll mark your answer as the accepted answer. You deserve 1000 points for your constant help. Thanks a lot.